# Cannot make change between Traditional and Romanized keyboard layout Nepali?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 16.10

[Look At this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99CMW.png)  According to [this](http://ltk.org.np/keyboard_layouts.php) , it is clearly said that Nepali language can be switch to Traditional layout and this is what i wanted but I am unable to do it and find the settings they mentioned. I just choose language to Nepali and default was Romanized layout and i need is traditional. In that website the settings they mentions are using older version of ubuntu which doesn't match for now. I am using ubuntu 16.10 Please Help me to switch to Traditional keyboard layout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install the `ibus-m17n` package.
- Log out and log in again.
- Open *System Settings -> Text Entry*, click the + button and select *Nepali (trad (m17n) (IBus)*.
- Repeat the last step for *Nepali (rom (m17n) (IBus)*

Comment: No, same only  one result with Nepali.  There is no option trad and rom.

Comment: @AppleAppala: If you open _System Settings -> Language Support_, is **IBus** selected as the "Keyboard input method system"? (It ought to be, since it's default in Ubuntu.)

Comment: ya, there's IBus selected by Default..

Comment: I checked again in Text Entry and I found both as u mentioned. Thank's man !! You kept my day alive! ;)